# Como faço para alterar a imagem de cada item da minha lista ?

Tags: android, listview, netbeans

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero Alterar a imagem de cada item da minha lista.. como faço ? Agradeço a compreensão eis que não tenho muita experiência. Obrigado. Meu código Abaixo.

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import br.gestaoBd.BancoDeDados.ProdutoDao;
 import br.gestaoBd.Beans.ItemDoPedido;
 import br.gestaoBd.Beans.Produto;
 import br.gestaoBd.listaadapters.ProdutoAdapter;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class ListProdutos extends Activity implements  AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView lista;
ArrayList<Produto> produtos;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_produtos);
    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    lista.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    atualizar(null);
}

public void atualizar(View view) {
    ProdutoDao proDao = new ProdutoDao();

    produtos = proDao.getListagem("");
    lista.setAdapter(new ProdutoAdapter(getBaseContext(), produtos));
    setTitle("Lista de produtos(" + CadPedido.getTotal() + ")");
}

public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent cadProdutoIntent = new Intent(this, CadProdutos.class);
    cadProdutoIntent.putExtra("Produto", produtos.get(position));
    startActivity(cadProdutoIntent);
    return true;
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    final ItemDoPedido itemAdicionar = new ItemDoPedido();
    itemAdicionar.setProduto(produtos.get(position));
    itemAdicionar.setValorUnitario(produtos.get(position).getPrecoDeVenda());
    // get prompts.xml view
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ListProdutos.this);
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_qtdeitem, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListProdutos.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

    final EditText edQtdeAddItem = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edQtdeAddItem);

    // setup a dialog window
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    itemAdicionar.setQuantidade(Double.parseDouble(edQtdeAddItem.getText().toString()));
                    CadPedido.getItensDoPedido().add(itemAdicionar);
                    ListProdutos.this.atualizar(null);
                    Log.i("AULA", "Finalizou");
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    // create an alert dialog
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Continuar");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == 0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(ListProdutos.this,
                CadPedido.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Meu Adapter:

```
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import br.gestaoBd.Beans.Produto;
   import br.gestaoBd.R;
   import java.util.List;

   public class ProdutoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<Produto> produtos;


public ProdutoAdapter(Context context, List<Produto> produtos) {
    this.context = context;
    this.produtos = produtos;
}

public int getCount() {
    return produtos.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return produtos.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return produtos.get(position).getId();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Produto produto = produtos.get(position);

    LayoutInflater layout = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = layout.inflate(R.layout.linhapro, null);

    //Log.i("AULA", "Montou:" + produto.getDescricao());
    //Log.e("ERRO", "Valor da variavel estava nullo!");

    ImageView imgImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imgImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sem_foto);

    TextView edDescricao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    edDescricao.setText(produto.getDescricao());

    TextView edPreco = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    edPreco.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getPrecoDeVenda()));
    return view;
}
}
```

Peço encarecidamente que sejam bastante específicos .. Muito Obrigado Colegas !

Comment: Creio que seja apenas adicionar um resource da sua imagem na pasta drawable, e substituir ali em  `R.drawable.sem_foto` para `R.drawable.seuResource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro é estruturar sua class **Produto**, saber o que ela possui se é **nome,preço,imagem e etc...** Sabendo disso você cria ela com construtores e get e set. E saber também **se essa** **imagem vai ser local ou de um servidor remoto**. Exemplo:

```
public class Produto{


public Produto(){}

private String nome;
private Float valor;
private String urlImagem; // ou caso local private int IdImagem;

metodos de get e set aqui...
```

}

Depois na sua class **ProdutoAdapter** no metodo **getView**

```
    ImageView imgImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imgImageView.setImageResource(produto.getIdFoto); //caso a imagem seja local (esse id é como se fosse isso: R.drawable.minhaImagem)

TextView edDescricao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
edDescricao.setText(produto.getDescricao());

TextView edPreco = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
edPreco.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getPrecoDeVenda()));
```

Lembrando quando se trabalha com imagens no Android é sempre bom ter cuidados com a memória do celular do usuário pois é alocado uma grande quantidade de memória e ocorre o erro FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.
E mais caso seja Imagens de um servidor procure tutoriais na internet que existe bastante caso faça e tenha dúvidas poste aqui e alguém vai tentar te ajudar

Comment: Estou fazendo como sugeriu e ele não reconhece o getIdFoto que no meu caso está nomeado como IdImagem pois é assim que está na classe Produto.. @Alessandro Barreto

Comment: Qual erro ela dá? certifique-se de ser um valor int porque R.drawable.tuaImagem é um valor inteiro

Comment: ele não reconhece o getIdImagem .. diz que não pode encontrar a variável @Alessandro Barreto

Comment: Mas esse erro ocorre quando você compila o projeto e monta o apk? Como você está passando as imagens para a class Produto?  É no seu Produto Dao?

Comment: Sim pelo ProdutoDao .. na verdade ele não chega a reconhecer o getIdImagem , não chega nem a compilar